# How can I get to the same match with my friend in Tom Clancy's Ghost Recon Phantoms?

Tags: steam, ghost-recon-phantoms

My friend and I are friends on Steam, and we want to play in the same team or at least in the same match. How can we do that?

Comment: I look forward to seeing an answer to this!

Answer (score 2):

You need to go to the in-game social tab and add your friend to your friends list. Then you can add him to a *FireTeam* (which is essentially a party system) and then you can start games together.